# Spearman correlation plot in corrplot

Tags: r

[![enter image description here][1]][1]I have a data set with Yes No values for Cancer and underlying risk factors (e.g.agefirstchild). Below an example of the data set

```
set.seed(42)
cancer <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
agegroup <- sample(c("35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
agefirstchild <- sample(c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater", "nullipareous"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
dat <- data.frame(cancer, agegroup, agefirstchild)
```

I would like to run a Spearman correlation plot that looks like this[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This plot comes from the corrplot package. But when I apply this code for my data set it gives me an error. *Error in matrix(if (is.null(value)) logical() else value, nrow = nr, dimnames = list(rn,  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [3] not equal to array extent*
Images are available at links under code, and below the description:

[![Corrplot][2]][2]

[![Correlation plot from example below][3]][3]

And where in the code can I add the method, I need Spearman? It doesn't necessarily need to be exactly the same as below but similar format and with values in the plot

````
corrplot(dat, method = "color", col = col(200),
       type = "upper", order = "hclust", number.cex = .7,
       addCoef.col = "black", 
       tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 90, 
       p.mat = p.mat, sig.level = 0.01, insig = "blank", 
       diag = FALSE) ```


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkKLY.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrghy.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHUEe.png
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to:

1)make your variables numeric factors first and then
2)create the spearman correlation matrix and then
3)create the plot according to the created matrix

```
    set.seed(42)
cancer <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
agegroup <- sample(c("35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
agefirstchild <- sample(c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater", "nullipareous"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
dat <- data.frame(cancer, agegroup, agefirstchild) 

#make numeric factors out of the variables
dat$agefirstchild <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$agefirstchild))
dat$cancer <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$cancer)) 
dat$agegroup <- as.numeric(as.factor(dat$agegroup))

corr_mat=cor(dat,method="s") #create Spearman correlation matrix

library("corrplot")
corrplot(corr_mat, method = "color",
     type = "upper", order = "hclust", 
     addCoef.col = "black",
     tl.col = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks! @siimpoldre The graph in your example looks good. When I run exactly the same, I get a graph where all the metrics are squeezed. In my complete dataset there are way more metrics. See link for the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHUEe.png

Comment: Try changing the "tl.cex" argument in the corrplot() function smaller; or resizing (making bigger) the window where your plot is displayed; or maybe making the variable names shorter.

Comment: Hi thanks where can I add the tl.cex argument in the corrplot function? How to integrate?

Comment: you can write it inside the brackets in corrplot() something like: corrplot(corr_mat, method = "color",
     type = "upper", order = "hclust", 
     addCoef.col = "black",
     tl.col = "black", **tl.cex = 0.7**). The default is tl.cex=1, so anything under 1 makes he text smaller and over bigger. PLay around with it and see what works

Comment: Hey thanks it works I have a visible plot now. Thinks it is best if I get to change the fontsize of the numbers, because there is still some overlap

Comment: For that you can add into the corrplot() function **number.cex** argument and see what size fits.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variables are all categorical, perhaps a mosaicplot would be a better graphic.

```
mosaicplot(~cancer+agegroup+agefirstchild, data=dat, shade=TRUE)
```

[image]
Nothing looks significant.

Or using the **vcd** package (for improved labelling):

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(~cancer+agefirstchild+agegroup, data=dat, shade=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Edward, thank you! The plots look nice, but would like to have a plot like below

Comment: I suggest you read up on Spearmans rank correlation. Your data are not continuous and, except for age group, are not ordinal. Therefore, presenting correlations for your variables are not appropriate.

Comment: Hi thanks I go and read. I also go and read about these plots. Is it also possible to have values in these squares? So you can better see what they represent?

Comment: What values would you like? It's certainly possible to put text in the rectangles, but it is probably too difficult and not worth the effort. The values can be seen from the colour, which is explained in the bar on the right. Increasing shades of blue represent frequencies that are more than you would expect while shades of red represent frequencies that are less than expected.

Comment: Ah now I see that the white boxes represent a value :) I thought I am missing colors but everything is in the white box. That is clear. So it actually show then which sub variables have an increased chance for breast cancer, that is insightful to be able to visualise it like this. I spoke to my statistics teacher and he indeed said. Nominal variables can not be used for Spearman, ordinal can. I accepted your answer as well, but maybe you can only have 1 accepted answer

Comment: I've made the plot but a bit too much variables  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkKLY.png

Comment: It's pretty but there are so few cancers. And these types of graphs have a limitation for the number of variables you can effectively show. Long labels are also problematic.